# Removing index.php from my joomla website url?

Tags: joomla

I am using Joomla in my website, and if found all the articles that i create in Joomla has link structure like

`"http://www.mysite.com/index.php/about-us"...`

How do i remove the index.php from the link? so that my link would look like

`"http://www.mysite.com/about-us"`

FYI : I have configured joomla with IIS.It seems .htaccess file have some role to play in this,but it seems to be not working in IIS. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This configuration should work:

http://docs.joomla.org/SEO_and_IIS#web.config

Answer (score 0):

You can configure that in the adminpanel of joomla. Go to the general settings and activate `mod_rewrite`

Comment: it is already activated in my website.. its mentioned like "Use Apache mod_rewrite" do i need to do anything different for IIS?

Comment: mod_rewrite is an apache-module. There is something similar for IIS, though I am not familiar with IIS. Since you activated the feature in the joomla backend, and it's not working, I assume that joomla only supports the apache module and not the IIS-module...

Comment: so we cannot remove index.php from the url when we use IIS?

Comment: at least not from the joomla-backend. but as i said - (i just rechecked it) there is a native IIS rewriting module. its syntax looks like xml. With the help of this module you could rewrite the urls manually, removing the `index.php`. Since I am not familiar with IIS, I can't provide further details.

Answer (score 0):

Look here:

http://expressionengine.com/wiki/Remove_index.php_From_URLs/

I don't really know how to use it, but hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just rename the htaccess file by putting the (.) before the file name and remove the extension
and all is done.